# Linux Mint 12 two finger scrolling

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad, scrolling

i can't get two finger scrolling to work for anything on Linux mint 12 64bit.... hp dv7 laptop.  the hardware definitely supports it as it works just fine on my windows partition.

following the instructions here:
http://robert.orzanna.de/2011/06/06/enable-two-finger-scroll-in-linux-mint-11-and-ubuntu-11-04/

i created a

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-twofingerscroll.conf

file and add the following information:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "touchpad catchall"
MatchProduct "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "8"
Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "40"
EndSection
```

based on this link:

http://jaisejames.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/to-enable-touchpad-tap-on-click-two-finger-scroll-in-linux-for-laptop-users/

i also tried a slightly different conf file

```
Section "InputClass"
      Identifier "touchpad catchall"
      Driver "synaptics"
      MatchIsTouchpad "on"
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
      Option "HorizScrollDelta" "0"
      Option "TapButton1" "1"
      Option "TapButton2" "2"
      Option "RBCornerButton" "3"
      Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "1"
EndSection
```

i've also been to Settings > Mouse >Touchpad and enabled two-finger scrolling. this does nothing but kills all scrolling since edge-scrolling is no longer enabled.

i've also installed gpointing device settings and tried enabling it that way per the instructions here:
http://craiglayne.com/linux-mint-enable-two-finger-scrolling-multitouch/

and i still can't get two finger scrolling to work.  this is driving me crazy, not to mention i still have about 2-3 other problems with mint while trying to make the switch away from windows.

any further ideas?  am i missing something obvious?  let me know if you need any more information from me.

**edit**:

the following terminal commands DO finally enable two-finger scrolling.  however, they are lost every time i reboot.

```
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient EmulateTwoFingerMinW=5
synclient EmulateTwoFingerMinZ=48
```

I found this xorg configuration that definitely works on my Samsung Series 7 for enabling the clickpad!
https://gist.github.com/2382480

Comment: The edit about `synclient` enables it for me! The only issue now is to find out how to disable the touchpad while I'm typing. Thanks!!

Comment: For what it's worth: This works automatically in newer versions of Linux Mint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-twofingerscroll.conf`. Generally speaking, never modify files under `/usr`, except under `/usr/local`. These files are under the control by the package management system. The configuration files that you can edit are under `/etc`.

By default, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, the configuration file for the X server (the part of the GUI that talks to the hardware), does not exist. If you want to customize it, you first need to create a file with suitable contents. Run this command from a text console (only if `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` doesn't exist already!):

```
sudo sh -c 'Xorg -configure >/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

See [Howto find my xorg.conf. Where is it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18991/howto-find-my-xorg-conf-where-is-it) and [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config) for more information.

Once you've created the file, you can add that `InputClass` section.

Alternatively, you could arrange for `synclient` to run whenever you log in. This would make the two-finger scrolling a per-user setting rather than a system-wide setting. See [Is there a standard way to have a program start when a user logs in on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12576/is-there-a-standard-way-to-have-a-program-start-when-a-user-logs-in-on-linux); [Auto running bash script on login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32599/auto-running-bash-script-on-login)

Comment: i do have a xorg.conf but not a xorg.conf.d folder.  i tried putting the inputClass secion into xorg.conf but on reboot only got a black screen.  have to jet right this second, but will look more closely at your links later.

Comment: well i did a reinstall last night, and that solved a different problem i was having (sound icon and usb sound) but still leaves this one. running your sudo command returns: /etc/X11/xorg.conf: Permission denied the links seem to indicate that i can't run that while X is active

Comment: @helgatheviking Sorry, the redirection should have been within the scope of `sudo` (see my edit). Be sure to check that you still have no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` before running that command, since it would be overwritten. If you want to review the output of `Xorg -configure`, you can write it to a different file.

Comment: great thanks! according to : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics i shouldn't edit xorg.conf but instead put things in a xorg.conf.d/ directory, which i tried to no avail.  figured it was worth a shot even though i know that arch is a different distro.  also i did a reinstall, which fixed my sound icon troubles, but now the synclient commands don't even seem to enable the two-finger scrolling anymore like they used to, so the startup script idea wasn't working either.  grr... pulls hair!

Comment: @helgatheviking If your system has an `xorg.conf.d`, use it. It's relatively new, not all distributions have it. You may need to allow `synclient` in `xorg.conf`, see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=115196

Comment: it didn't have a xorg.conf.d, but i made one.  didn't seem to work out well but didn't break X either.  many thanks for your continued help.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/foo.conf` is for examples, afaik. Copy your edited file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/foo.conf` and reboot.

(Btw, came here via Google because my Synaptics touchpad suddenly has no two-finger-scroll after the last dist-upgrade. Don't know reason, didnt need `.conf` before.)

Comment: i read some of the .conf files in the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d folder and they do seem to indicate examples.  but there is no /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d folder, are the changes meant to go in /etc/X11/xorg.conf ?

Comment: the answer was definitely no. got a black screen had to boot into a live session and restore the copy i had made of xorg.conf.  i did get this working once with some synclient commands but it didn't "stick" between reboots

Comment: @helgatheviking If you have no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`, you need to edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, and first you have to make one; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on:
http://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-two-finger-scrolling-in-linux-mint/:

- Go to Mouse and Touchpad settings
- Choose the Touchpad tab
- Under the Scrolling section, choose Panel Layout
- Select "Two Panel Scrolling"