# Two-finger scrolling on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, touchpad, scrolling

I recently installed Mint 17 Cinnamon on my laptop and am not able to get the Two-finger scrolling to work. I have changed the Panel Layout to Two-finger scrolling in system settings but that doesn't help.

Also, I have followed the answers here: [Linux Mint 12 two finger scrolling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35148/linux-mint-12-two-finger-scrolling)  and added the lines from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Configuration) but that doesn't help either.

I copied `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` to `/etc/X11/` and my `/usr/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "VertEdgeScroll" "on"
        Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
        Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "on"
        Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on
# non-synaptics clickpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
#       To disable the bottom edge area so the buttons only work as buttons,
#       not for movement, set the AreaBottomEdge
#       Option "AreaBottomEdge" "82%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

I did a reboot as well but Two-finger scrolling still does not work.

Comment: I'm using mint 17 on my laptop and two-finger scrolling just works, i haven't done anything special.  Are you sure your driver/touchpad supports it?

Comment: The two-finger scroll works just fine on my windows.

Comment: Try running `evtest` on the input device in question. It is possible it is not registering multiple pointers simultaneously.

Comment: @AJMansfield I ran the evtest. You were right. it is not registering multiple pointers simultaneously.  Could you suggest a possible fix?

Comment: @Ajax Unfortunately, I'm just as clueless as you in that respect. (Actually, probably more so, as I don't have the machine in front of me here.)

Comment: It might help to add information on the exact hardware in use.

Answer (score 3):

Use the command:

```
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
```